# Before fetching data from DB checking row null or not

Tags: php, laravel

I fetching data from DB and passing to Google Map. But sometimes in address table, lat and lng rows are being empty. So if it happens and I use that half empty array Google Map is crushes. So when I fetching data in Controller is there any option like; if row empty go next row... For example:

```
public function index()
{

    $Data = DB::table('allestates')->whereNotNull('lat')->whereNotNull('lng')->get();

    return view('home', 'Data');

}
```

Of course this is not proper code but, I just want to show what I am trying. Is this possible?

Comment: Use `where` filter.

Comment: The above query just return arrays of all db data not return a row. Please explain your question

Comment: Why don't you check whether result is empty. If empty don't use google map.

Comment: I update the codes in the question. I am trying to get rows have value. I don't want to get null rows... @InzamamIdrees

Comment: I using map because some rows have value I just to pass null rows @Shashidhara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `whereNotNull`:

```
public function index()
{

    $Data = DB::table('allestates')->whereNotNull('lat')->whereNotNull('lng')->get();

    if (!empty($Data)){

    }
}
```

The filter you used (`where('lat','lng')`) actually means "records where the field lat has the value 'lng'".

Comment: Thank you. then I don't need `if (!empty($Data)){

    }` because it will fetch just the rows with value?  if I don't understand wrong. I updated the question with the codes. is it the right usage?

Comment: Yes, just a small detail: to pass the data to the view, you need to pass it as an array: `return view('home', ['Data' => $Data]); `

Answer (score 0):

you can add check if a field is not null by using below code:

```
$Data = DB::table('allestates')
                    ->whereNotNull('lat')
                    ->whereNotNull('lng')
                    ->get();

if (!empty($Data)){

}
```